# Default styles editor wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, editor, text-editor

I have a wordpress site which has styles made from the beginning to affect the original text editor wordpress .

For example:

If the text editor , in the "Visual " tab, I put a left-aligned image , this does not align , I assume that the class that you are placing the editor does not exist. This applies also to the " p " tags have different styles which you placed the editor ( "visual" tab).

Having explained this, how do I put classes and original styles of the "Visual " tab of the editor , so that it functions as it should ?

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom stylesheet for the visual editor.

In your theme *functions.php* :

```
function my_editor_styles() {
  add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-editor.css' );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_editor_styles');
```

Then in your *custom-editor.css* file, add your rules in this way to prevent any conflict with WP admin:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: No don't touch that, it's part of the WP core. If you need to change something, as everything else in Wordpress, overwrite it.

Comment: the problem is, the site was made of beginning, the theme was made of beginning, since zero, for this reason, when a put any option in the editor, this not work it very well, the style and class of the options to the editor are not.

Comment: If the theme provide its own stylesheet for TinyMCE, look for any `add_editor_style` call that would reference it in the theme folder.

Comment: ok, i found the .css of editor. question: this .css are the styles of the each options of the editor "visual" tab ??

Comment: This stylesheet is applied to the whole visual mode, yes.

Comment: ok, explained it, only i have to put the code "my_editor_styles" in the functions.php or i have to put the tag link fot this file .css ?

Comment: What do you don't understand? If your theme already have a stylesheet for the visual editor, then edit it. If not, then do as explained in my answer - add the hook in _functions.php_, create the _custom-editor.css_ file then put your css rules inside it.

Comment: the dont have the stylesheet, i created the hook in functions.php and create the custom-editor.css but not appear the tag style in the inspector element in the browser. For this reason i do the question..

Comment: The stylesheet is not included through a style tag - if you look into the source when on the editor you should see a JS object on the top named `tinyMCEPreInit` - you'll see your stylesheet name somewhere inside it. Anyway that means you don't have to do anything else - the `add_editor_style` function does the necessary include for you.